# How can I return the Distance columns when the Mac and ScanGroup column matches for ALPHA,BRAVO,CHARLIE in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am trying to trilaterate device positions and need to isolate those three measurements. B8:27:EB:B6:96:76 is present for all three and I would like to match on that.
[image: SELECT * FROM Table;]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please show us the result you want for this sample data, as tabular text.

Comment: Its a mariaDB.  The image is from a [SELECT * FROM ScanResults] sql query.

Comment: Im trying to render something like  [ Mac    |    FirstTimeSeen    I    ALPHA_Distance   I  BRAVO_Distance    |   CHARLIE_Distance ]

Comment: [SQL EXPORT](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Invictus252/stackOverflow/master/export.sql)

Comment: Would I be better putting ALPHA,BRAVO,CHARLIE into their own tables and doing a double INNER JOIN?

Comment: @JasonSmith that isn't necessary; you can skip the part about putting them into their own tables, and just query them separately with a subquery in your JOIN statements. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as MariaDB does not have the PIVOT feature to do exactly what you want, you can simply perform subqueries.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
  a.Mac,
  a.ScanGroup,
  a.FirstTimeSeen,
  a.distance as alpha_distance,
  b.bravo_distance,
  c.charlie_distance
FROM ScanResults a 
JOIN ( /* hi, I'm pretending to be a new table */
      select Mac, ScanGroup, distance as bravo_distance 
      FROM ScanResults 
      WHERE DeviceName = 'BRAVO') b on a.Mac = b.Mac and a.ScanGroup = b.ScanGroup
JOIN (
      select Mac, ScanGroup, distance as charlie_distance 
      FROM ScanResults 
      WHERE DeviceName = 'CHARLIE') c on a.Mac = c.Mac and a.ScanGroup = c.ScanGroup
WHERE a.DeviceName = 'ALPHA'
  and a.Mac = 'B8:27:EB:B6:96:76';
```